# axios not returning the status of called api if error in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, axios, xmlhttprequest, http-status-code-401

I am using `axios` to make apis calls in react. If there is no token provided or token got expired server sends the `401` status. I want to check that status on reactjs side.

But if i check err object in `catch` the status field is null.

Here is the code

```
try {
      MyService.getIntet(reqBody);
    } catch (err) {
        handleUnAuthorizedResponse(err);
    }
```

on the error this shows this type of info.
[image]

In the service

```
import axios from "axios";
```

and the function

```
static getIntent(reqBody) {
    const url = `${this.intentionBaseUrl}/process`;
    const options = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
    };
    return axios
      .post(url, reqBody, options)
      .then((res) => res.data)
  }
```

HOw can i handle `401`?

Answer (score 0):

The error you've logged does not have a status because the request ended in a `Network Error`, which is not a 401.
You could check if it's a `CORS` problem, or else.

Otherwise, to manage the 401, seems good to use the `handleUnAuthorizedResponse` passing the error that should contain:

```js
const err = {
 ..., // other things like the request etc
 code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST',
 response: {
  status: 401, // status code
  statusText: 'Unauthorized',
  data: {} // data if the server sends some, like error messages, etc
 }
}
```

Comment: server is working, if i paas the valid token the request is served with response, if the token is missing server explictly sets the status 401